# Calculating coordinates of vertices, given dimensions in an architectural floorplan

Tags: coordinate-systems, education, fixed-points, floating-point, dimensional-analysis

So, one of my friend is trying to learn autocad. They were given a floorplan. The floorplan had the dimensions. And they were asked to find the coordinates of the all the vertices of the plan. So we were able to calculate the coordinates, but we wanted to validate the process that we followed and perhaps try a few more examples. But I am unable to find any resource online, that has any such example. Any help in this will be highly appreciated.
Also if anybody can advise the whole process giving the example would be a huge help. TIA [Floorplan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETCZb.jpg)

Comment: What type of floor plan? "Floor plan" is quite broad, what is the shape? Can you include the problem that you and your friend completed as an example? What are you asking here? A generalization of a problem? Making your question as clear as possible is a must.

Comment: I have added the floorplan in my question. So in that floorplan, we have been asked to calculate the coordinates of all the vertices, starting from the origin, which is assumed to be on the bottom left hand side of the image. So the first coordinate would be (25,0) and so on.

Comment: So what do you need help with? What is it you are asking of us?

Comment: So basically, just trying to figure out. If there is an online resource, that we can follow to solve a problem of this type. A link to a website perhaps? Where a person has shown the whole process of calculating the coordinate points on the example floor plans.

Comment: Why not create the problems yourself? Why might you need these extra problems? Are you struggling with these or just enjoy solving the problems? I would suggest searching for "find missing length of irregular shapes" problems, then try to find the vertices yourself.

Comment: While this situation is one that uses mathematics, it isn't really a mathematics question. It is about understanding drafts. For resources on that, you should be asking in forums for fields that use drafting. Either architecture or engineering. That is where you will find people who have undergone training in drafting, and would be most likely to know the sort of resources you are looking for. In this forum, while pretty much everyone is capable of understanding your problem, few will likely know of the resources you are seeking.